# Obtener la URL del Endpoint en el frontend dinámicamente desde el navegador

Tags: javascript, vue.js, api, rest, endpoint

En mi empresa se nos plantea la siguiente situación:

Estamos desarrollando una aplicación Web usando ***Vue*** como framework frontend y ***Spring Framework*** para el backend.
Tanto Backend como Frontend estarán alojados en contenedores de Docker en un servidor privado de nuestro cliente. En el futuro necesitaremos desplegar la misma aplicación a otras empresas en servidores de su red privada, al igual que en el primer caso.

Las consultas que realiza el frontend a los métodos REST utilizan un Endpoint hard-coded dentro del código de la aplicación en Vue para comunicarse con el backend.

La idea es poder desplegar la misma aplicación para todos los clientes futuros sin necesidad de tener que modificar la IP de las rutas Endpoint que están hard-coded para apuntar a los nuevos servidores cada vez y tener que volver a transpilar el código.

Para ello hemos pensado en 2 opciones:

1. Utilizar **JAVASCRIPT** (window.location.hostname y quedarnos con la parte de la IP) en tiempo de ejecución para que se obtenga la parte del Endpoint que es la IP del browser del usuario y componer con este dato el Endpoint para las consultas a la API Rest.
2. Utilizar los **ENVIRONMENTS** de Vue para ir añadiendo las diferentes IP de los servidores de los nuevos clientes y seleccionar la opción correspondiente a la hora de transpilar el código para ponerlo en producción (lo cual nos llevaría nuevamente a tener que transpilar el código cada vez pero modificando únicamente una línea del environment correspondiente y no en todas las partes del código).

No sabemos si las 2 opciones son válidas o si hay una mejor que otra en cuestiones de buenas prácticas o rendimiento y si pueden ocasionar algún problema que se nos pueda estar escapando.

Espero haberme expresado con suficiente claridad...

Comment: yo estoy haciendo exactamente lo mismo. mi solucion fue: en base a variables de entorno, se setea la URL del backend y esta es insertada en la generacion del Index.html osea, cada vez que una persona consulta a la plataforma, lo primero que llega en un index.html desde el backend el cual tiene procesada la ruta de su backend segun la variable de entorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la opción 2 es mucho mejor.

Imagina que en otra de las empresas futuras a implantar dicha solución quieren que estén en distintos servidores el backend y el frontend, este escenario no permite la ejecución de la opción 1 ya que la DNS no es la misma y haciendo window.location.hostname no llegarías a tu host de backend.

La opción 2 solo con hacer build del .env que quieres ya tendrías todo cambiado. No quieres hacer build, personalmente creo que el build de vue es bastante fiable, no suele dar errores y es relativamente rápido con aplicaciones grandes (No se el tamaño de tu app).

Answer (score 0):

Si te decantas por la opción 2, tal vez no sea necesario realizar el build del docker cada vez. He desarrollado una utilidad tonta que hace que la aplicación vue pueda cargar variables de entorno del docker. Por lo que con un build tienes solucionado el tema.

Con `npm install jvjr-docker-env` se instala. Para más referencias ver [README](https://github.com/juanise/jvjr-docker-env)
yo la he usado tanto en vue como en react y funciona ok.